# Blender model gets extra bits when opened in unity

Tags: unity

I have this weird issue when i try to move a model made in blender to unity my model will get extra bits in unity.

Viewed in blender:
[image: Blender Image]

Viewed in unity:
[image: Unity Image]

Anybody had this issue before? If so how did you fix this?

Comment: Do you have any hidden objects in your Blender scene? (The eyeball in the top-right Outliner is greyed out)

Comment: Are those planks made as separate objects? Is the scale applied for those objects  prior to exporting? (Object mode > Ctrl+A > Scale)

Comment: Yes all planks are duplicates of others. When i try applying the scale i get the error: Can not apply to a multi user: Object.

Comment: I don't have any hidden objects in my scene

Comment: Alright, I found a way to get around that error and managed to apply the scale. Now it's working as intended. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @MrZak if you send it as an answer, I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: I will not, you can add your own or mark this as duplicate of already existing. Related answers -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44313/scaling-and-importing-from-blender-to-unity and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation. The error you got was because objects were created as linked duplicates (Alt+D) so they were linking to one mesh datablock which prevents from applying any transforms.